# Current logged-in user in stackmob

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parse-platform, stackmob

I'm trying to get a list of contacts for the user that is logged in, but I can't figure out how to find the current user. I know from Parse.com you use Parse.User.current() does Stackmob have anything like this?

Code below to demonstrate what i'm looking for.

```
$(window).load(function () {
        var user = StackMob.User;
        var Contacts = StackMob.Model.extend({ schemaName: 'contacts' });
        var myContacts = new Contacts();
        var q = new StackMob.Collection.Query();
        q.equals('sm_owner', user);
        q.orderAsc('FirstName'); //sort by title in ascending order
        q.setRange(0, 9); //get the first 10.  second 10 would be setRange(10,19)
        myContacts.query(q, {
            success: function (model) {
                console.debug(model.toJSON()); //JSON array of matching Todo objects
            },
            error: function (model, response) {
                console.debug(response);
            }
        });
    });
```

I got what i was looking for using the code below but having ('sm_owner','user/thomas') is sort of useless.

```
$(window).load(function () {            
        var Contacts = StackMob.Model.extend({ schemaName: 'contacts' });
        var myContacts = new Contacts();
        var q = new StackMob.Collection.Query();
        q.equals('sm_owner', 'user/thomas');
        q.orderAsc('FirstName'); //sort by title in ascending order
        q.setRange(0, 9); //get the first 10.  second 10 would be setRange(10,19)
        myContacts.query(q, {
            success: function (model) {
                console.debug(model.toJSON()); //JSON array of matching Todo objects
            },
            error: function (model, response) {
                console.debug(response);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to do this using StackMob's [schema permissions](https://developer.stackmob.com/tutorials/security/Access-Controls%3a-Schema-Permissions).

For example, you can set up permissions so that your users can only read `contact` objects that they themselves have created.

When a user creates an object, the `sm_owner` field is automatically set to the currently logged-in user.  To take advantage of this, you can set up the `contacts` schema to only allow a user to read their own contacts. This way, filtering by current user is done server-side and you don't have to specifically query for it on the client.

**How to set this up:**

Go go Schema Configuration and Edit select your schema. Under Schema Permissions, choose `Logged In Permissions -> Allow to sm_owner` for `Read`, `Update`, and `Delete`.

Now when you query the `contacts` schema, only `contact` objects where (`sm_owner` == the current user) will be returned. Then you can simply remove this line:

```
q.equals('sm_owner', 'user/thomas');
```

Comment: It's worth noting that you'll get a 401 unauthorized response if you try to fetch something that you don't have access to.  For example if Read is only allowed to "Any Logged In User", and you aren't logged in, you'll get a 401 response and the error callback will be executed.

Comment: Meanwhile your/Justin's example above, to what Justin said, even though there may be many contacts in the database, only thomas's will be returned because the Read permission is set to "owner".  The server will hence only return the object instances that are permitted.  This is why you can remove the `q.equals('sm_owner', 'user/thomas')` line.  It happens automatically on the server side thanks to the permission you set.

Comment: But if you really do need to build a query using the current username, you can use the [getLoggedInuser](https://developer.stackmob.com/sdks/js/api#a-getloggedinuser) method.